# drag and drop a circle inside another circle with re size and auto adjust

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to create category(larger circle) and then sub category(smaller circle) such that  such that #category is a parent of #subcategory using D3 js.

Something like https://www.droptask.com/

*I need to drag and drop the circle inside the #category circle, which i am able to do.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530

I want to resize and auto adjust the circle which  i can drag that circle to the another circle it becomes a sub category of a circle.

I am not able to use force in pack layout properly. Can Someone pls suggest a way.

Comment: Your question title is vague and too long, kindly re frame the title. What you trying to achieve is possible i believe there is no examples for such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Here is how I would approach the problem.

Create  group  hierarchy.

Lets say you cave categories & sub categories. I would do it like this.

```
<g id='category'></g>
<g id='sub_category'></g>
```

Regardless of what shape you want to have, you can draw them inside the groups.

```
<g id='category'>
   <circle>...</circle>
   <circle>...</circle>
</g>
<g id='sub_category'>
   <circle>...</circle>
   <circle>...</circle>
   <circle>...</circle>
</g>
```

Now you can write drag events. for category circles. 
in order to to drop the subcategory to a category,  create a '`mouseover`' event for the category group, Set a boolean when you are over a category circle, When you drop the sub category make sure the boolean is set. (obviously you have to unset it on `mouseout`).

I hope you get the idea. Give it a try. Come back with your work & we can help more.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle for the work. Below is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/shishiruu/r1mz2apr/2/  I want my sidebar elements to drag and append to the rightSection group. And elements of rightSection are also draggable. This looks to be working. When i drag the rightSection onload circle(#id1) to any point and then drag and drop the left section then i am not able to position the inner circles. How can i solve this issue? And I think i am not using the group elements effectively. Please suggest !! Thanks

Comment: What is your current issue?

Comment: My current issue is that i am not able to figure out how to apply force layout on <jsfiddle.net/shishiruu/r1mz2apr/3> such that outer circles are not overlapped with other outer circles and all inner circles are not overlapped with other  inner circles. Thanks again.